# Absence of partitionKey field in a partitioned collection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

DocumentDB is truly schema less implies it will not enforce you to have only certain kind of document and it's a choice by user.

Considering the above point in a partitioned collection (lets say department as partitionedKey in Employee document) the user decide not to pass any partitionKey(just a use case to support my point, a new employee/intern joined and not yet decided on which department he will work and later they might update the document with appropriate department)

Based on the above scenario my question is, In the interim period, to which partition the new employee will go/persist,  as I don't have a department(partitionKey) for him?

```
{
  "eid": "",
  "entryType": "",
  "address": 
  {
    "PIN": "",
    "city": "",
    "street": ""
  },
  "name": "",
  "id": "",
  "age":
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question! We had same query when we started working with partitioned collections.

Based on my understanding, it is certainly possible to create a document in a partitioned collection without specifying partition key attribute (departmentId in your case) though it is not recommended.

When such things happen, Cosmos DB puts such documents in a special partition that are accessible by specifying `{}` i.e. `empty JavaScript object` as partition key in your query.

However, please keep in mind that you can't update the partition key attribute value (an employee is assigned a department in your example). You must delete and recreate the document with correct partition key.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav, is there a way to know from which partition my documents are coming from while querying?

Comment: I'm note sure I understand your question. Can you please elaborate? It may not be a bad idea to ask a new question.

Comment: The third paragraph took me ages to track down! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a partitioned collection then you'll be required to provide a value for partitionKey on every insert. The choice of what to use as a partitionKey is based on the needs of your application and the nature of your data. There is no one size fits all answer. From the sounds of things you might want to reconsider using department as a partitionKey.

Comment: Not true. It is entirely possible (though not recommended) to create a document in a partitioned collection without specifying a partition key.

Comment: @Jesse I was able to insert a document without partitionKey, but my doubt is on which partition it resided, is there a way to know from which partition my documents are coming from while querying?

Comment: Ah, I was going off of the behavior when using the Gremlin APIs and attempting to do an insert without partitionKey throws an error.